# Is it possible to export a few data frame to the one CSV in R

Tags: r, csv

I have a few data frames here, which are ReportDoD, ReportMoM, ReportYoY and ReportQoQ. I was able to export each of it to its individual CSV file. But I was wondering if I can export this 4 reports into 1 single CSV files, in 4 separate sheet. Thanks.

```
write.csv(ReportDoD,"C:\\Users\\Desktop\\ReportDoD-D(%).csv", row.names = FALSE)
write.csv(ReportMoM,"C:\\Users\\Desktop\\ReportMoM-D(%).csv", row.names = FALSE)
write.csv(ReportYoY,"C:\\Users\\Desktop\\ReportYoY-D(%).csv", row.names = FALSE)
write.csv(ReportQoQ,"C:\\Users\\Desktop\\ReportQoQ-D(%).csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "4 separate sheet". CSV files don't have sheets (they are not Excel files). You could append the data frames and write them to one CSV file, if you added a column to identify each data frame and if the columns are the same in each.

Comment: Have a look at `bind_rows` in package `dplyr`, also consider `write_csv` from package `readr` as an alternative.